# Easeljs: mouse events stop working

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, easeljs

I am implementing a touch animation with the EaselJs library.

When I read am image from a local folder all mouse events are working OK, like: onPress.

But when I choose an image source from a URL like:
http://www.visionale.net/wp-content/uploads/cool-accessories-car.jpg

mouse events, like onPress, stop working.

Try for example to dragAndDrop from library and change image link "img/x.jpg" to any link from internet.

Answer (score 1):

That's the <canvas> crossdomain issue (security feature).

There is a workaround: you can use a simple 'proxy script' on your server.
This one is pretty nice: http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/